# how to add dailymotion.com videos in html website

Tags: html, video

I want so serve some videos on my site. They are available as .MP4 files gotten from a FlipShare camera.

Now I tried converting them to WMV (which succeeded, but when embedded in html in a tag, users have to install an addon and the user experience of 10 Windows Media Players on the site isn't just so good.)

```
<object id='mediaPlayer' width='320' height='285' classid='CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95' etc
```

So then I looked at youtube and wondered how they do it, but I can't figure out what format they convert the video to.

So my question is: What format do I have to convert my video to, to show it in a player which does not need to be installed in the users browser. What tool do i need and what is the html code to embed such a video?

As you can see: starting from scratch.

PS: I often hear: This or that file extension is just a container, there can be anything inside. If you're using this in your answer, can you explain this to me, because I never understood this. For me a .cs is a c# file and a .doc a Word file, and not 'a container'.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need any tools or something kind of that. HTML5 has `video` tag, which allows you to play videos easilly. Video tag has three different (video) formats to use. These are .mp4, .webm, and .ogg. All of those have different video and audio codecs, which makes them not so cross-browser-compatible.. I suggest to use .mp4, because looks like, that it's the best supported (and you seem to bring videos in mp4). But according to mozilla developer network, it seems like using multiple sources is possible.

Okay, there's an example for HTML5:s video tag.

```
<video width="320" height="285" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <!-- mp4 video -->
  Your browser doesn't seem to like video tags...
</video>
```

Or if you want to use multiple file types:

```
<video width="320" height="285" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <!-- mp4 video -->
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm"> <!-- webm video -->
  Your browser doesn't seem to like video tags...
</video>
```

If you don't like `video` tag for reason or other, there's lots of flash video players in the depths of net. For example [JW player](http://www.jwplayer.com/about-jwplayer/), [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org) or [Video.js](http://www.videojs.com/)

So if you want to convert your videos, i suggest mp4 and webm to get the best support in `video` tag. You can use [Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/), or [Format Factory](http://www.pcfreetime.com/) to converting videos.

Your PS question: all the files are just plain text(you can see it by opening image file in text editor), but programs parse those texts to i.e. png images or say, word documents.

Comment: And a good software to convert videos to `.mp4` and `.webm` is [Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/)